# Python bs4 and request how to print text that is scrambled with numbers and sign in between the letters

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup, request, python-requests, http-proxy

I am currently working on a script that pulls info from `http://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/all/accessories` from the uk server 
before I had successfully written a chunk of code that can gather this info perfectly from the us website

```
for item in soup1.find_all('div', class_='inner-article'):
    url = item.a['href']
    alt = item.find('img')['alt']
    req = requests.get('http://www.supremenewyork.com' + url)
    item_soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'lxml')
    name = item_soup.find('h1', itemprop='name').text
    style = item_soup.find('p', itemprop='model').text
    print alt +(' --- ')+ name +(' --- ')+ style
```

But I want this script to pull info from the uk website and so I wrote a proxy thing for it to be able to accses the website and pull the code 
This worked for me

```
UK_Proxy1 = raw_input('UK http Proxy1: ')
UK_Proxy2 = raw_input('UK http Proxy2: ')

proxies = {
    'http': 'http://' + UK_Proxy1 + '',
        'https': 'http://' + UK_Proxy2 + '',
}

r1=requests.get('http://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/all/accessories', proxies=proxies)


soup1 = BeautifulSoup(r1.text, 'lxml')
```

But when I run the script I get this error

`name.text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'`

and I know why this happens In the us website the name of the item is perfectly fine and shows up in the html like this 
`Supreme®/Hanes® Crew Socks (4 Pack)`
But on the UK website the name and the colour are scrambled and show up like this:
s`&#65279;`up`&#65279;`reme`&#65279;`hanes`&#65279;` etc......
(you get the point)
on the uk website the name and colour are scrambled but there is a solution around this You must make the script look for a letter one by one 
Unfortunately I am not sure on how to do this 
Im thinking something like .replace # with '' or .remove or something like that

If anyone may assist me I would greatly appreciate this

Comment: check encoding, then try to use `import html` and `html.unescape(h1)`

Comment: @nickanor would you mind maybe going into more detail and providing an example?? I am getting this error    html.unescape(h1)  
  AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'unescape'  Maybe could you provide on how I would write this into my code? (keep in mind im using python 2.7)

Comment: currently i used the above sample in python3..

Comment: @nickanor where would i place this in the code and do you think they will work for python 2.7